# Transform Translate with Positive Value make a scrollbar

Tags: css

I try to make a mobile menu: http://animesector.budi.upperyard.de/

You can see at the top Header Bar 2 Menu Buttons.
The right one give the Content area transform(translateX(-200px));
The left one give the Content area transform: translateX(200px);

The Negative (-) value dont create a Scrollbar horizontal Scrollbar...
But the Positive one does. have anyone any solution for this problem?

I tried to give the div around a overflow: hidden; but this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can prevent the horizontal scrollbar with `overflow-x: hidden` in the `body` element. Tried it right in the browser with dev tools and worked perfectly.

Comment: Yeah this is the only solution that works for me, but the problem is that this make problems in some mobile devices =/ one of the problems is that, user cant reaload page while he is drawing the browserwindow down. i place in body the overflow: hidden, open the page and try to reload the website ;) you will see that this dont work anymore...

overflow-x: hidden; works... but... then i dont see while im designing the rest of the page, when any element goes out of the body tag... =/

Comment: Could you be more specific on the part about elements going out of the body? I'm not sure I get what you mean. Maybe it's a problem that could be solved by disabling overflow-x only when designing.

Comment: This solution dont works for Chrome on Android... The page is still scrollable.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but I dont want overflow hidden because i have a dynamic tree that might expando sideways, however when translatedx even the empty sides give me right scrollbar at the beginning :S

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue. In the end I avoided the menu getting scrolled off the screen using `translateX` - I used the `scale` transform instead.

Your site is not visible anymore, but probably this is what you did to make the menu visible by transitioning:

`translateX(-200px)` -> `translateX(0)`

I used the scale to achieve somewhat similar transform:

`scale(0,1)` -> `scale(1,1)`

```
.menu { 
    transition: transform 150ms ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: top right;
    transform: scale(0,1);
}

.menu.open { 
    transform: scale(1,1);
}
```

Yes, there is a difference in the animation but it's probably not even recognised by most users if it happens fast.

No overflow manipulation needed.